# Using Elasticsearch and filebeats how do I only execute my pipeline on certain files?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, filebeat, elasticsearch-painless

I only want to run my pipeline on files where the log path contains a certain keyword, how do I do this within the pipeline?

Pipeline (removed my pattern and patterns as it is not relevant):

```
{
  "description" : "...",
  "processors": [
    {
      "grok": {
        "if": "ctx['log']['file']['path'].value.contains('keyword')",
        "field": "message",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In Kibana I see I have log.file.path available as metadata, and I just want to run the pipeline if it contains a keyword, but I get a runtime error because of my if statement.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I think the problem lies with how I am trying to access the log.file.path field as I don't know how to reference it correctly from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use the Drop processor
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/drop-processor.html

```
"drop": {
   "if": "ctx.log.file.path.contains('keyword');"
}
```

You can find more complexe exemples here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest-conditional-complex.html

Comment: I thought the drop processor prevents the document from being indexed if skipped? I would like it to be indexed just not run through my pipeline.

Comment: ok just not beeing processed by the grok processor? If so can you try the same synthax of the "if" of the drop in the IF of your grok processor ?